Postgres Timezone Conversion Issue
I am trying to wrap my head around the following conversion in Postgres:
select 
  timestamp with time zone '2024-08-28 12:00:00Z' at time zone 'UTC'    as utc_time,
  timestamp with time zone '2024-08-28 12:00:00Z' at time zone 'UTC+02' as expected_2pm,
  timestamp with time zone '2024-08-28 12:00:00Z' at time zone 'WHYDOESTHISWORK+02' as expected_error,
  timestamp with time zone '2024-08-28 12:00:00Z' at time zone 'CEST'   as got_2pm_now




utc_time
expected_2pm
expected_error
got_2pm_now




2024-08-28 12:00:00.000
2024-08-28 10:00:00.000
2024-08-28 10:00:00.000
2024-08-28 14:00:00.000



It looks to me like the UTC+02 is actually just a +02, which happens to shift values as in UTC-02, but why?
I am using postgres 14.9

You need to read POSIX Time Zone Specifications. In particular: One should be wary that it is easy to misspell a POSIX-style time zone specification, since there is no check on the reasonableness of the zone abbreviation(s). For example, SET TIMEZONE TO FOOBAR0 will work, leaving the system effectively using a rather peculiar abbreviation for UTC. Also: The positive sign is used for zones west of Greenwich. (Note that this is the opposite of the ISO-8601 sign convention used elsewhere in PostgreSQL.)
